# How to select a option of pop menu without option tags in selenium?

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

Hi~i want to click 'Furniture' option of a pop menu in a website in selenium

when i open tag element, i find there was no real option tag which would shows text 'Furniture',

Below is my screenshot:

[Pop menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoXcY.png)

[pop menu tag image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjgz4.png)

```
   <div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-8--value-item">Furniture</span></div>
```

The traditional way of selenium to deal with this is :

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('pop_menu')[1].click()
```

or

```
options=Select(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("pop_menu"))

options.select_by_value("Furniture")
```

BUT!

This situation has no 'Furniture'option tag!!

it seems like  java script or  things like that control pop menu selection

i don't know how to handle it

i tried click pop up roll and send down-arrow key one by one until the tag text show 'Furniture',However, i still want to figure it out how to 
directly click on target tag

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshots it looks like a "dropdown".
As you cannot select by option, you can select by text, in this case using xpath.

First, you will be clicking on the "dropdown" and after clicking on the span that contains the Furniture text.

```
#open your dropdown.
driver.find_elemebt_by_...("DROPDOWN").click()

#select the value
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Furniture']").click()
```

Comment: Sorry.console shows 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:' cause there is no 'Furniture ' tag,you have to click Furniture bar in pop up menu,then that span content changed to 'Furniture',the same as 'Vehicle' ,'Household' category bars like that.the whole html content even doesn't contain a 'Furniture' word except you click that pop up menu bar,i dont know why.

Comment: Hi @Super-ilad, I'm still trying to understand the steps, the print of the html that you sent has the 'Furniture' text, what is the default state of this menu? at the beginning. can you provide this? html at the default state, html after you open the pop up, and html after you click.